# Getting rid of \r\n strings

Tags: php, encoding

I have a form into which I entered a newline character which looked correct when I entered it, but when the data is now pulled from the database, instead of the white space, I get the \n\r string showing up.

I try to do this:

```
$hike_description = nl2br($hike_description);
```

But it doesn't work. Does anyone know how this can be fixed?  I am using PHP.
And here is the page where this is happening.  See the description section of the page:
http://www.comehike.com/hikes/scheduled_hike.php?hike_id=130

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You also have a stray `\'` displaying on the page.  How are you saving / loading data in the database?  You don't want to both sanitize and use parametrized queries at the same time, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means, you have probably **plain text** '\n\r' strings in the db.

Try to sanitize db output before display:

```
$sanitized_text = preg_replace('/\\[rn]/','', $text_from_db);
```

(just a guess).

**Addendum**:

Of course, as [Col. Shrapnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145557/getting-rid-of-r-n-strings/5145983#5145983) pointed out, there's something fundamentally wrong
with the contents of the database (or, it is used this way by convention and you don't know that).

For now, you have fixed **a symptom partially** 
but it would be much better to look for the reason for these escaped characters
being in the database at all.

Regards

rbo

Comment: Why use resource-extensive preg_replace?! str_replace() can do that faster even like this: `$sanitized_text = str_replace(array('\r\n', '\n\r'),'',$text_from_db);`

Comment: @Shehi: in this case, you are probably correct with assuming str_replace() would be more effective than preg_replace(). But the  array temporary doesn't (for me) look very efficient too ;-)

Comment: @Genadinik that's wrong approach. Why noone in the world is trying to think when answer? Why so direct and straightforward answer, without even attempt to think one step further?

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Sure.
Your code doing unnecessary escaping, most likely before adding text to the database.
So, instead of replacing it back, you have to find that harmful code and get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) to clean up the input.

```
$hike_description = nl2br(str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $hike_description));
```

Comment: "\r\n" (which is a sequence of two control chars: 0x0D and 0x0A) wouldn't probably show up on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$hike_description = str_replace(array('\n','\r'),'',$hike_description);
```

You may want to read up on the differences between the single quote and double quote in PHP as well: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thanks, but why didn't this work? $hike_description = nl2br($hike_description);